# Laravel Sold Items Count

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want count the Sold items for every Seller.
I try to change this Code:

```
<?php $count = DB::table('purchases')->whereIn('seller_id', [4])->count(); echo $count; ?>
```

Can i add an other $DB command in it?

```
{{$product->seller->id}}
```

Like this for example instead of `[4]`:

```
<?php $count = DB::table('purchases')->whereIn('seller_id', [{{$product->seller->id}}])->count(); echo $count; ?>
```

Comment: try ->where(['seller_id' => $product->seller->id])

Comment: Oh yes thats was! Many Thanks

Comment: great! I'm happy to help you

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

In your Seller Model

```
public function purchases(){
    return $this->hasMany(Purchase::class)
}
```

then

```
$seller = Seller::withCount('purchases')->find(4);

echo $seller->purchases_count;
```

or

```
$purchases = Seller::find(4)->purchases;

echo $purchases->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a count for a group of users, you can use whereIn with an array of seller ids.

But if you want a count for each seller, you should use grouping

```
->groupBy('seller_id')
```

so that your query could look like:

```
$user_info = DB::table('purchases')
             ->select('seller_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->groupBy('seller_id')
             ->get();
```

Comment: I would not use raw statements, unless needed

Comment: I agree. [Prefer to use Eloquent where possible](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#prefer-to-use-eloquent-over-using-query-builder-and-raw-sql-queries-prefer-collections-over-arrays)